# Azure Service Bus CancelScheduledMessageAsync - unable to catch MessageNotFoundException when sequence number no longer exists

Tags: azureservicebus

I am scheduling Azure Service Bus messages using `ScheduleMessageAsync`.

```
var sequenceNumber = await sender.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, sendMessageOn)
```

I sometimes need to cancel these messages.  I do this by calling `CancelScheduledMessageAsync`.

```
await sender.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber)
```

Sometimes the `sequenceNumber` is no longer valid (message was already queued, etc).  To handle these exceptions I wrap the call to `CancelScheduledMessageAsync` in a `try catch` with an exception filter for `MessageNotFoundException`.

```
try {
    await sender.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber)
} catch (Exception ex) when (ex is MessageNotFoundException) {
   _logger.LogError("Ignored MessageNotFoundException)
}
```

This does not work.  The exception is thrown but the catch block never executes.

```
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: Messages not found. One or more sequence numbers missing. ... (MessageNotFound)
```

Removing the exception filter so that I catch all exceptions works which suggests that I am filtering on the wrong exception but I don't think I am.

Hopefully I'm just too tired and overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `MessageNotFoundException` is part of `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` but I'm using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.  For `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` the following does the trick:

```
try {
    await sender.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber)
} catch (ServiceBusException ex) when (ex.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MessageNotFound) {
   _logger.LogError("Ignored MessageNotFoundException)
}
```

Note the change to the exception filter.  Instead of catching or filtering on `MessageNotFoundException`, we catch `ServiceBusException` and filter on `ServiceBusException.Reason`.